# How do you find / search / query for vendors / customers by name in QBD?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have a use case where the user types in a customer or vendor name and it returns basic information from QB, address, balance...

In Qbo I do the following;

```
cust_query = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CustomerQuery()
cust_query.name = "CUSTOMER NAME"
cust_query.SpecifyOperatorOption(Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.FilterProperty.Name, Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.FilterOperatorType.EQUALS)
cust_query.ExecuteQuery
```

So my question is, how do I do the same thing in Qbd?
I can't seem to find any examples or documentation.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info on constructing a query in the DevKit is here: adding a query
http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0200_DevKits/0100_IPP_.NET_DevKit/Query_Filters/QuickBooks_Desktop_(Windows)

If you just want to know how to do it in the REST service.
http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Customer

You can use a query attribute of FirstLastEnd, FirstLastStart, FirstLastInside.

thanks
Jarred

Comment: I have seen both of these docs before.  Either I am not seeing something or dumb, likely both, but I can't seem to figure out how to specify name as a search parameter from these.

Comment: Should really have said "Company Name".

Comment: @FreddyMac You can't search by the "Company Name" field using the IDS APIs.  :-(

Comment: In v3 you can use Simple Query Language to construct a SQL like query to get vendors from a certain company, in v2 you cannot, you would pull back a list and parse it by company name in your app.

Comment: v3 isn't released yet, so "you can" should really be "you will be able to" (not trying to be a jerk, just want to make sure we don't send someone on a wild goose chase trying to figure out how to connect to v3)